# Desktop and mobile hero image for email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

I am looking to build a template in Exacttarget and know how to display 2 different hero images based on desktop and mobile for regular HTML but have never set one up in exacttarget. This will be on a per email basis. Is it possible to have 2 url fields for an image block? 1 for the desktop image and then the other for the mobile image.

Comment: You can always edit the HTML in the particular content block... You are not limited to the UI input field for img url.

Comment: hope these helps you https://css-tricks.com/comparing-various-ways-to-hide-things-in-css/ ... https://www.actionrocket.co/email-design-review/email-code/hiding-elements-in-email-4922 ... also as suggested by Lukas, I suggest to use HTML block over FreeForm, if you/your team has necessary skills

Comment: Thanks for your answers! This I know how to do but since this is getting handed off and the template will be used for multiple emails. The preferred method would be to use the UI input field the img block has to offer.